# CakePHP Filter Component - correct usage to filter a period of time

Tags: cakephp, datetime, components, filtering, period

I am quite new to CakePHp and the MVC way of thinking.

Up to know I was able to create a Resultsetfiltering by the use of the Filter Component by Nik Chankov successfully.

The way I am using it, is to call it in my Controller, saving the condition statement and passing it to my Paginator.

Now, I have one column which holds a 'created_at' date and I want to give the user a possibility to enter a start date and an end date and to pass it to the filter component.

I tried creating two input fields 'created_after' and 'created_before' and to join these to an array[created_at][BETWEEN] in my controller since the Filter Component handles 'BETWEEN'. Unfortunatelly, if I unset the original values created_before and _after, they won't be saved to the session by the filter component and if I don't I get a SQL Error since the component will create a statement including 'created_after' and created_before' which are not defined in my database.

What would be the correct way of doing this? Please give me advise how and into which direction I should proceed to solve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should add logic to your model to protect it from this type of misuse by a controller.

There are predefined callback functions you can access in your model to change the request data before searches are performed. It sounds like you want to add some logic to the beforeFind() method.

cookbook: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1049/beforeFind
API: http://api13.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelbeforeFind

Without a code sample, it's hard to suggest an exact solution, but something like this:

```
// app/models/yourmodel.php
beforeFind() {
    if(/*yourlogic*/) {
        unset($queryData['yourmodel']['created_after'];
        unset($queryData['yourmodel']['created_after'];
    }
}
```